# Wix Domain Route to AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cname, a-records, url-masking

I have a domain at my WIX Account. I have an AWS EC2 Instance. For URL Masking, I approched this URL link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZh7sqs1YFo.
Therefore, I created a Hosted Zone in AWS Route53 as it says. I added A Record Set and CNAME Record Set. I changed domain **Host** **points to** in the Wix to the AWS EC2 Instance Public IP Address.

[Wix Domain Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eckHS.png)

Then when I wanted to change the Name Servers in the Wix, it said to not editable fields in the Name Servers.

[Name Servers are not editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ktWz.png)

So domain is working without the **www**. If I use **www**, it stays to the user on the WIX site otherwise it forwards to the AWS EC2 Instance site but I want to use **www** so I changed CName to my WIX Domain CNAME.

[WIX CNAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dizv.png)

But **www** is not working for my AWS EC2 Instance, it stays the old one WIX Site URL and when I try to reach without www, it takes to the user on the AWS EC2 Site.

I want to know whether I am going to right way or if I am wrong please correct me in this problem.

Comment: I added Apache Rule Engine in AWS EC2 Instance `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
` And it works for **http** not for **https**

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?

If you are trying to obscure web pages and create a proxy model then the best way to accomplish this it to use the [wix-router](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-about-routers) capability.

Comment: Sir, My problem was that my website on the wix and after sometime I created a custom website on AWS EC2 instance. I just need that AWS EC2 instance website run on the WIX URL. And I added RewriteEngineRules so that works now for http only not for the https.